# error handle in promise nodejs + postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, error-handling, promise

I just start learning nodejs below is my code ...
Q1. Do I handle the error message correct way with `insertUserPendingBase()`??
I check the return message if equal `success` or not.  And if so what is the `then` can do in this example?

Q2. I use `pg` when I do execute the query do I need to do anything for prevent SQL injection? I saw in document there's no need, but I'm not sure..

any suggestions can improve my code will be welcome

routes

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var co = require('co');

// .. post
var insertUserPendingBase = function(token) {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    var query = "INSERT INTO user_pending_base (user_pending_email,user_pending_password,token_timestamp,token) VALUES ('" + user_email + "','" + user_password + "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'" + token + "')";
    dbClient.query(query, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        fulfill('success');
      }
    });
  });

  // .then(function(value) {
  //   console.log(value);
  //   throw "error message";
  // }).catch(function(e) {
  //   console.log(e);
  // });
}

co(function *() {
  // ...
  var insertUserPendingBaseResult = yield insertUserPendingBase(generateTokenResult);

  console.log('insertUserPendingBaseResult:'+insertUserPendingBaseResult);
  if (insertUserPendingBaseResult == 'success') { // handle error like this ??

  }

  res.render('Account/Register/Index', {
    partials: {
      Content: 'Account/Register/Content',
    }
  });
}).catch(onerror);

function onerror(err) {
  console.error(err.stack);
}
```

**Update**

If I change `fulfill(result)` instead of `fulfill('success')` I will get below object but there's no message about fail or success

```
{ command: 'INSERT',
  rowCount: 1,
  oid: 0,
  rows: [],
  fields: [],
  _parsers: [],
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false,
  _getTypeParser: [Function] }
```

**Update 2**

I find a way use `try` and `catch` inside `co(function *()` like below, but I'm not sure is this the best way make a clean code ?

```
co(function *() {
... 
try {
  var insertUserPendingBaseResult = yield insertUserPendingBase(generateTokenResult);
  // if success ...

} catch (err) {
  // if fail
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: If you want to use node-postgres via promises, check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

Answer (score 1):

Cannot comment on SQL injection, but `fulfill('success')` must be `fulfill(result)`.

To handle success and failure of the `promise` you should use `then` and `catch`, no need for generators:

```
insertUserPendingBase.then(function(result) { /* handle result here */ })
                     .catch(function(ex) { /* handle exception here */ })
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and the example code let me understand how to use `then` and `catch` !  I'm just paste a part of my code ,  I need to crud other tables depends first table return result. So I don't want too many callback inside `then` .

Comment: If I use `generators`  should I return result like `fulfill(result)` instead  `fulfill('success')`  ?  and how to catch the error after execute?

Comment: `fulfill(result)`, but I don't see why you want to use `generators`.  In many ways they are just a stepping stone toward ES7 `async` / `await` which you can already have today with `babel`.